# Run test on different version of chrome with Protractor

Tags: protractor

I know I can run the same test in a different browser with Protractor, but I need to run the test on different versions of chrome. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

1. you can do it in [browserstack](https://www.browserstack.com/automate) for sure, but the license is expensive. You can try to look up similar services that are cheaper.
2. Another option is to look up older versions of chrome, remove current version, install another one, find corresponding chromedriver version here `https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/LATEST_RELEASE_$CHROME_VERSION` where `$CHROME_VERSION` is major version (eg `85.0.4183`). And then run Protractor

But 2 reasons why I wouldn't do #2:

1. As it's seen, it requires too many steps
2. Google doesn't support older versions of chrome for a good reason of security vulnerabilities, that all internet know of, so it's potentially risky to use third party website downloading those